# The page isn’t redirecting properly Laravel

Tags: laravel

I've been trying to make a conditional based on authentication, even though, my browser tells me this: `The page isn’t redirecting properly` which lets me know something of course is wrong.

Here are my routes:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() { // If the user is logged in
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@dashboard');
});

$router->group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() { // If the user is not logged in
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
});
```

Comment: You are calling the same endpoint with 2 different middleware. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use the route '/', because if I log in the user and redirect him to `/home` he would still be able to access the main screen (`/`) (which is not relevant and confusing).

Comment: It is unfortunately not possible, you can just remove the first router group and if you need some specific logic can create your own custom controller

Comment: Maybe just add some javascript that automatically redirects...?